# How to update multiple time pickers separately

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, timepicker

The past few days I’ve been experimenting with time pickers in Xamarin.Android. I've followed these two links:

[How to update text-view with multiple datepickers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20738960/how-to-update-text-view-with-multiple-datepickers?lq=1)

http://blog.falafel.com/31-days-of-xamarin-android-day-15-controls-datetime-controls/

But I’m now a little stuck.

I’ve two time pickers in the same activity. I want to choose a start time and an end time. But when I set the time of one of the time picker in the activity it automatically updates the other one.

What I want is set one time picker without updating the other one. 
Below is what I’ve tried:

**ReservationHoursActivity.cs**

```
public class ReservationHoursActivity : Activity, TimePickerDialog.IOnTimeSetListener
{
    private TextView time_display_Start;
    private Button pick_button_Start;
    private TextView time_display_End;
    private Button pick_button_End, submitButtonMyslot;

    private int hour;
    private int minute;

    const int START_TIME_DIALOG_ID = 0;
    const int END_TIME_DIALOG_ID = 1;

    const int TIME_PICKER_TO = 0;
    const int TIME_PICKER_FROM = 1;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
        SetContentView (Resource.Layout.ReservationHoursLayout);

        time_display_Start = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.timeDisplayStart);
        pick_button_Start = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btnPickTimeStart);

        time_display_End = FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.timeDisplayEnd);
        pick_button_End = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btnPickTimeEnd);

        submitButtonMyslot = FindViewById<Button> (Resource.Id.btnSubmitSlot);

        submitButtonMyslot.Click += SubmitButtonMyslot_Click;

        pick_button_Start.Click += delegate {
            ShowTimePickerDialog (START_TIME_DIALOG_ID);
        };

        pick_button_End.Click += delegate {
            ShowTimePickerDialog (END_TIME_DIALOG_ID);
        };

        hour = DateTime.Now.Hour;
        minute = DateTime.Now.Minute;

        UpdateDisplayStart (hour, minute);
        UpdateDisplayEnd (hour, minute);
    }


    void ShowTimePickerDialog (int pickerID)
    {
        switch (pickerID) {

        case TIME_PICKER_FROM:
            var dialogStart = new TimePickerFragment (this, hour, minute, this);
            dialogStart.Show (FragmentManager, null);
            break;

        case TIME_PICKER_TO:
            var dialogEnd = new TimePickerFragment (this, hour, minute, this);
            dialogEnd.Show (FragmentManager, null);
            break;
        }

    }

    public void OnTimeSet (TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
    {
        UpdateDisplayEnd (hourOfDay, minute);
        UpdateDisplayStart (hourOfDay, minute);
    }

    void UpdateDisplayStart (int selectedHours, int selectedMinutes)
    {
        time_display_Start.Text = selectedHours + ":" + selectedMinutes;
    }

    void UpdateDisplayEnd (int selectedHours, int selectedMinutes)
    {
        time_display_End.Text = selectedHours + ":" + selectedMinutes;
    }
}
```

**TimePickerFragment.cs**

```
public class TimePickerFragment:DialogFragment
{
    private readonly Context context;
    private  int hour;
    private int minute;
    private readonly TimePickerDialog.IOnTimeSetListener listener;

    public TimePickerFragment (Context context, int hour, int minute, TimePickerDialog.IOnTimeSetListener listener)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.hour = hour;
        this.minute = minute;
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public override Dialog OnCreateDialog (Bundle savedState)
    {
        var dialog = new TimePickerDialog (context, listener, hour, minute, false);
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

I don’t know how I can update the two time pickers separately. 
I’ve also tried to put the OnTimeSet method inside this:

```
private TimePickerDialog.IOnTimeSetListener From_Time_Listener = new TimePickerDialog.IOnTimeSetListener()
    {
        public void OnTimeSet (TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
        {
            UpdateDisplayEnd (hourOfDay, minute);
        }
    };
```

But that doesn’t work. It is not allowing me to put that method inside. Besides, other variables and methods will be unexpected if I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you could solve this.  The easiest might be to set a class level variable that tracks which picker is active, and then use that value to determine which fields to update when the picker completes:

```
int activePickerID;

void ShowTimePickerDialog (int pickerID)
{
    activePickerID = pickerID;

    switch (pickerID) {

    case TIME_PICKER_FROM:
        var dialogStart = new TimePickerFragment (this, hour, minute, this);
        dialogStart.Show (FragmentManager, null);
        break;

    case TIME_PICKER_TO:
        var dialogEnd = new TimePickerFragment (this, hour, minute, this);
        dialogEnd.Show (FragmentManager, null);
        break;
    }

}

public void OnTimeSet (TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
{
    if (activePickerID == TIME_PICKER_TO) {
      UpdateDisplayEnd (hourOfDay, minute);
    } else {
      UpdateDisplayStart (hourOfDay, minute);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public void OnTimeSet (TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute)
{   
if(pickerID == TIME_PICKER_FROM){
    UpdateDisplayEnd (hourOfDay, minute);
}
else if(pickerID == TIME_PICKER_TO)
{
    UpdateDisplayStart (hourOfDay, minute);
}
}
```